# Return peak heights in find_peaks

Tags: multidimensional-array, indexing, indices

I am using scipy.signal.find_peaks in a 8x150 array "signal" to find relative minima.

for example for row 1, I use

```
peaks = find_peaks(signal[1,:],distance=8,height=-1.6)
```

This realiably gives me the indices in a ndarray that has the indices and the peak_heights as a property arrary.

Now I would like to return the peak heights in a list or so, so that I can save them for later use.

I have tried
signal[1,peaks]
but that gives me an index error.

How do I convert peaks to a proper indice? Or is there a way to directly access the peak_heigts from find_peaks?

Answer (score 0):

I just found that signal[0] seems to do the job!
Thanks!